# How do I join two tables with the same composite key, and use values from T2 if not in T1 using MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have two tables with the same column names, and the same composite primary key.  The composite primary key of both tables is id + year.  I want to always use data from table T1, and if there exists an id + year from table T2, that's not in table T1 I want it to be returned also.

Here's my tables

T1

```
id  |  year  |  cost
----+--------+-------
1   |  2012  |  1.01
2   |  2012  |  1.02
2   |  2013  |  1.03
```

T2

```
id  |  year  |  cost
----+--------+-------
1   |  2012  |  2.01
2   |  2013  |  2.02
3   |  2013  |  2.03
```

I want to get:

```
id  |  year  |  cost
----+--------+-------
1   |  2012  |  1.01
2   |  2013  |  1.02
2   |  2013  |  1.03
3   |  2013  |  2.03
```

This is obviously wrong, but I tried:

```
SELECT
  T1.id,
  T1.year,
  T1.cost
FROM employee_cost AS T1
  INNER JOIN (select
        employee_cost_historic.id,
        employee_cost_historic.year,
        employee_cost_historic.cost
          from employee_cost_historic) AS T2
    ON T1.id = T2.id
      AND T1.year = T2.year
```

Comment: can you explain your output?

Comment: My output is everything that is in table T1, plus the one row from T2 of id 3, year 2013, because that composite key doesn't exist in T1

Comment: from where is the 2nd record of your output coming i can't understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a `union all`:

```
select id, YEAR, cost
from t2
union all
select id, YEAR, cost
from t2
where not exists (select 1 from t1 where t1.id = t2.id and t1.year = t2.year)
```

Comment: Thank you, just what I wanted!

Answer (score 2):

Or another option with LEFT JOIN and IS NULL:

```
SELECT T1.Id, T1.Year, T1.Code
FROM T1 
UNION
SELECT T2.Id, T2.Year, T2.Code
FROM T2
  LEFT JOIN T1 ON T1.Id = T2.Id AND T1.Year = T2.Year
WHERE T1.Id IS NULL
```

Good luck.